# Why does rmarkdown crash rstudio when setting variables as ggplotly object but not in R script?

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown

I have a .Rmd file that renders an html with various plots and tables. Earlier today it ran fine but, all of a sudden, saving a ggplotly object as a local variable crashes rstudio. The ggplot runs fine in the markdown chunk, but the ggplotly function crashes rstudio. If I copy this code over to an R script, it runs fine and shows the resulting figure in the viewer. This is on a mac, R version 4.1.2

```
pets <- data.frame(
  pet = c(rep("dog", 5), 
          rep("cat", 5), 
          rep("fish", 5), 
          rep("bird", 5)), 
  foodcost = c(100, 90, 87, 75, 82, 
               55, 63, 71, 59, 58, 
               23, 35, 37, 34, 42, 
               17, 34, 23, 32, 30), 
  month = rep(c("April", "May", "June", "July", "August"), 4)
)

pet_plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(pets, 
                            aes(x = month, 
                                y = foodcost, 
                                color = pet, 
                                group = pet, 
                                text = paste0(
                                  "<b>Month</b>: ", month, "\n", 
                                  "<b>Food Cost</b>: ", round(foodcost, digits = 1), "\n", 
                                  "<b>Pet</b>: ", pet))) + 
  ggplot2::geom_point() + 
  ggplot2::geom_line() + 
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(
    values = c("dog" = "red", 
               "cat" = "orange", 
               "fish" = "purple", 
               "bird" = "green")
  ) + 
  labs(x = "Month", 
       y = "Price ($)", 
       color = "Pet") + 
  ggplot2::theme_bw()

pet_plot <- plotly::ggplotly(pet_plot, tooltip = "text")
```

I tried restarting rstudio, uninstalling and reinstalling r/rstudio. Reinstalling a number of packages including rmarkdown, plotly and ggplot2.